# Mudar a cor da barra de uma Navigation page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho isso:

```
public  void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginService svc = new LoginService();
            LoginRS res = svc.Login(txtUsuario.Text, txtSenha.Text);
            if (res != null && res.Success  )
            {
                App.LooggedUser = res;
                Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

            }
            else if(res != null && ! res.Success)
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = res.Exception;
            }
            else
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = "Não foi possível realizar o Login, por favor verifique sua conexão com a Internet";
            }
        }
```

como eu tinha uma TabbedPage, usei esse código, ajudado por uma colega aqui para criar a NavigationBar. Acontece que ela vem com a cor padrão(Azul) e necessito alterar para a cor cinza. Tentei um BackgroundColor, mas não tenho esse método nesse ponto do código. Existe um BarBackgroundColorProperty, mas não estou conseguindo nada até agora. Estou lendo sobre ele, mas ainda não consegui nada de concreto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você configurar a propriedade BarBackgroundColor da instância do NavigationPage:

```
new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.Gray };
```